# Convert 10000-element Vector{BitVector} into a matrix of 1 and 0 and save it in Julia

Tags: csv, julia, export-to-csv

I have a "10000-element Vector{BitVector}", each of those vector has a fixed length of 100 and I just want to save it into a csv file of 0 and 1 that is all. When I type my variable I almost see the kind of output I want in my csv file.

Amongst the many things I have tried, the closest to success was:

`CSV.write("\\Folder\\file.csv",  Tables.table(variable), writeheader=false)`

But my csv file has a 10000 rows and 1 column where each row is something like Bool[0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0].

Comment: You said *"10000-element Vector{BitVector}", each of those vector has a fixed length of 100"*. Can you please explain more? I didn't get what exactly is the shape of your data. Is it a vector of vectors?

Answer (score 5):

This is not the most efficient option, but I hope it should be good enough for you and it is relatively simple and does not require any packages:

```
open("out.csv", "w") do io
    foreach(v -> println(io, join(Int8.(v), ',')), variable)
end
```

(the `Int8` part is needed to make sure `1` and `0` are printed and not `true` and `false`)

Comment: If the commas are not necessary, then replacing the `join` with `String(v .+ '0')` would produced nice `0` `1` strings.